How to configure Visual Studio Code to recognize external stub files for Python development?
I'm developing a Python plugin that uses a specific external library. I have the following setup:

I'm using Visual Studio Code as my IDE
I have access to the stub files (.pyi) for the library I'm using
The library is not installed in my development environment, as it will be available in the runtime environment where my plugin will be executed

Currently, Visual Studio Code is showing error messages for objects from this library, marking them as unknown, even though they exist in the library.
Is there a config file where I can tell VS Code to search for the definition of the objects from the library in the directory of the stub files? If yes how can I edit them,
I tried to modifiy the settings. under .vscode in my project root. (You can do that in file, preferrence, setting)
According to  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference , I have to ovewrite stubPath and set languageServer to Default or Pylance
{
    "python.analysis.stubPath": "C:\\Program Files\\Stubs",
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",

}

But noting happends
I tried with other settings like "extapath" but it didn t work either

Have you tried to add the paths to your stub files in the extraPaths section in pyrightconfig.json which is in the root of your project directory.

@MingJie-MSFT I don t use the package pyright. And my team won t probably use it. I am looking for a general solution

This is similar to “python.analysis.extraPaths”： [“path/to/your/package”], you could try this settings. If allowed, you can also try adding the path to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

This solution works but this is not optimal
I can copy paste the .py in a directory in the project like that
root
+-- stub_directory
+-- mycode

it work but I have to write
 import sub_directory.importedfile 

instead of
 import importedfile

I can copy paste all pyi files directly in the root but that make the project more difficulty to read.
A best solution would be to add a configuration file somewhere in the project that enable pylance (a visual studio extension ) to enable visual studio to access the pyi files

what if you renamed  importedfile to __init__.py and renamed sub_directory to importedfile?
